# Amazon EMR questions

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I have to feed output from custom Linux application to Hadoop and it seems as Amazon EMR is a great way to experiment. I am really just beginning to look into Hadoop and Amazon documentation, so some advise would be appreciated...

Would I be able to run my application in SELinux environment?
Would I be able to deploy/execute my app (written in C++) on Amazon EMR nodes?
What would be the approach to get the output of app (string, double pair) into Hadoop in this environment?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.You can configure EMR instance as per your need.
2. Yes you can execute your c++ application if you install g++ in your
   EMR cluster.
   For above 2 use cases you have to access the master node in EMR.
   You can access master node with simple SSH.
3. One way is store your output of c++ application in file.Load that
   file to HDFS/S3.Use that file on HDFS as input to Hadoop.